# how to run a dynamic select in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Bear with me a bit

I want to run a `select` statement and the result should look exactly as if I ran that `select` myself result should be a `datagrid`, not a `dbms_output`?

```
DECLARE
  sql_stmt    VARCHAR2(200);
  sql_stmt2   VARCHAR2(200);
  ids         VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  ids := 5;
  sql_stmt:='select query from query_table where id = :id';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt using ids into sql_stmt2;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt2;
END;
```

but this gives me a

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at line 8
```

line 8 is

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt2
```

Comment: Missing terminating `;`?

Comment: ths egor, but i just forgot to add that ; in the question above, i did recieve the error and added the ; accordingly afterwards ora-06502 error came

Comment: Print query `sql_stmt2` before executing it.

Comment: To amplify what @EgorSkriptunoff said - we can't help you diagnose the problem if we don't know what `sql_stmt2` contains when the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` tries to run it.

Answer (score 0):

By my count line 8 is `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt using ids into sql_stmt2;`.

sql_stmt2 is defined as VARCHAR2(200).

I'd say your query returns a string with more than 200 characters.

Answer (score 0):

1) You don't need dynamic SQL to execute your first statement - all identifiers are known at the time of execution. Static SQL like

select query from query_table where id = p_ds;

where p_id is a parameter is the relevant choice.

2) Line 8 points the expression

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt using ids into sql_stmt2;

which has the wrong syntax, INTO clause has to be the first one:

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt INTO sql_stmt2 USING ids;

See Oracle documentation please:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm

To get the complete answer in your question please provide the real code and data example in your table.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try

```
ids number;
```

or

```
ids :='5';
```